# Set network in docker run from Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins

In the `docker run` step of my Jenkinsfile, I have the following:

```
docker.image('deployscript:latest').withRun("-e 'IMAGE=name:${BUILD_ID}' -e 'CNAME=name' -e 'CONFIG={\"HostConfig\":{\"NetworkMode\":\"host\"}}'") { c ->
    sh "docker logs ${c.id}"
}
```

When this gets deployed, the Connected network gets set to `bridge`, but I need it to be set to `host`.

I've tried adding these to the `withRun` parameters, but none seem to work:

- `--network host`
- `--network='host'`
- `--network=host`
- `--net=host`

How do I set the network to host in the Jenkinsfile `withRun` parameters?

With the first option (`--network host`), here's what actaully gets run:

```
docker run -d -e 'IMAGE=name:94' -e 'CNAME=name' -e 'CONFIG={"HostConfig":{"NetworkMode":"host"}}' --network host deployscript:latest
```

Why is the network still set to `bridge` with the command above?

I would expect one of these to work:

```
docker.image('deployscript:latest').withRun("--network host")
docker.image('deployscript:latest').withRun("--network='host'")
docker.image('deployscript:latest').withRun("--network=host")
docker.image('deployscript:latest').withRun("--net=host")
```

Comment: You should be able to just pass it alongside those `-e` options.  (That `-e CONFIG` option doesn't obviously do anything beyond set an environment variable; it won't affect the container's local network settings.)  What happens if you do add in the option?  How can you tell it doesn't work?  Do you actually need it?

Comment: When I add any of those 4 network params, it has no effect. The network is set to bridge and it doesn’t work unless it’s set to host.

Comment: @DavidMaze I added more details to my question. I guess one of my problems is finding documentation on how to specify docker commands from a Jenkinsfile. There's plenty of documentation on `docker run` itself, but I can't find much on `withRun`.